# Nested JSON not working as expected with HTTPie in Zsh

Tags: zsh, httpie

I can't figure out why sending nested JSON with HTTPie doesn't work as expected in Zsh. It looks like Zsh is trying to match bracket contents by default, but turning off matching (via noglob, nomatch, etc options) doesn't seem to work, and Httpie forms the literal foo[bar] instead of nesting the object:

```
> http --offline -v POST :/someurl foo[bar]=baz
zsh: no matches found: foo[bar]=baz

> noglob http --offline -v POST :/someurl foo[bar]=baz
POST /someurl HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, */*;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 19
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost
User-Agent: HTTPie/2.6.0

{
    "foo[bar]": "baz"
}
```

I'm using Httpie 3.0.2, and the same operation works as expected in Bash. I.e.:

```
{
    "foo": {
        "bar": "baz"
    }
}
```

Comment: Millet, would you be able to supply your configuration? Perhaps something third party is blocking for you. I've created a fresh docker image (with ubuntu base) and started zsh on it. https://gist.github.com/isidentical/4e2e9d6ccf7a7052af0311d5afa4191e. The first example (with noglob) works perfectly on it. Personally I use oh-my-zsh, and I know that noglob solution also works for it too.

Answer (score 1):

`[...]` is a globbing operator in most shells including zsh and needs to be quoted.

You'd have problems in other shells as well if there were some files in the current directory whose name matched that `foo[bar]=baz` glob pattern (try in bash/dash/ksh... after `touch foob=bar fooa=bar` for instance).

In bash and other POSIX shells, if no such file exist, the glob is passed literally by default, though the `failglob` and `nullglob` options can affect it.

Here, you need:

```
http --offline -v POST :/someurl 'foo[bar]=baz'
```

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. I tried the same example (with noglob prefix, as the use reported) and even though there are files named `foob=bar` / `fooa=bar` etc. it still works as usually and creates the *correct* JSON body.

Comment: @BatuhanTaskaya, I meant that `foo[bar]=baz` would be expanded to `fooa=bar` `foob=bar` in bash and zsh alike. If `http --offline -v POST :/someurl 'foo[bar]=baz'` gives different results in `zsh` and `bash`, that would suggest `http` is a different command in both shells, or that there are differences in the environment  that command receives when invoked in the different shells. What do `type http` return in both shells?

Comment: I meant with the `noglob` prefix (as the user has reported). In `zsh`, globbing is opt-out and in `bash` it is opt-in. That is behavioral difference. As far as I can tell, having files with certain names is not the real issue here (potentially something problematic config-wise).

Comment: @BatuhanTaskaya, in bash, it's not opt-in. There is glob expansion by default. The difference is that if there's no match, bash by default doesn't complain. But I have to confess I hadn't seen the OP's point about trying with `noglob` when answering, and I agree that the difference in behaviour between bash/zsh in that light cannot be explained by that globbing behaviour difference between the shells. Still, I'll keep that answer in as it's important to realise those glob operators must be quoted regardless of the shell.